# C++/Fortran project created with Visual Studio 2010/Intel 2013 will not build in release mode in Visual Studio 2015/Intel 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, linker-errors, intel-fortran

I’ve inherited a Visual Studio project created to run on Visual Studio 2010 / Intel 2013, that is a combination of both C++ and Fortran projects. I was tasked with making necessary modifications to enable the project to be built and run with Visual Studio 2015 with Intel Fortran 2017.  I’ve got everything compiling, building and running in debug mode, but I am unable to get it to build in release mode.  For all the Fortran projects that reference the C++ .lib project, I get the following messages:

```
MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG; add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker performance   
fatal error C1905: Front end and back end not compatible (must target same processor).
LINK : fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed
```

I’ve checked and double checked the configuration and all projects are being built for the Win32 platform.

Searching online, I’ve read that it might be due to optimizations being set differently for different projects.  I’ve played with the optimization settings which either does nothing or results in library conflicts.  I’ve searched online to try to resolve these conflicts and can’t seem to find a straight-forward enough solution that I can implement.

The project still builds and runs in Visual Studio 2010 in both debug and release mode.  I’ve even tried to build the new Fortran version with the .lib created from Visual Studio 2010 and get the same errors.

Is there something inherently different in the new versions of Visual Studio and Intel Fortran that are incompatible?

Answer (score 0):

Error C1905 states:

"Front end and back end not compatible (must target same processor)"

What does that mean and why does it happen? "This error occurs when an .obj file is generated by a compiler front end (C1.dll) that targets one processor, such as x86, ARM, or x64, but is being read by a back end (C2.dll) that targets a different processor."

"To fix this issue, ensure that you are using a matching front end and back end. This is the default for projects created in Visual Studio. This error may occur if you have edited the project file and used different paths to the compiler tools. If you have not specifically set the path for the compiler tools, then this error may occur if your Visual Studio installation is corrupt. For example, you may have copied the compiler .dll files from one location to another. Use Programs and Features in the Windows Control Panel to repair or reinstall Visual Studio."

You stated that you're trying to port over your project from 2013 to 2017, which would make sense as to why you can't get it to build and run in release mode as the compiler tools are most likely in different locations.

-MSDN